# Book series about a girl who has talismans

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read this book series about a girl who has talismans and the main antagonist represents a black onyx. She has a mentor who helps her learn about controlling stones and their powers, the peridot was used to make someone tell the truth and it was all fiction.

I thought it was called the talisman series but I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this? If you haven't already it would be worthwhile taking the [tour] and don't forget to register your account!

Comment: This is a common question, could you look through [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=magic+gems+is%3Aquestion) and see if any of these jog your memory? Also, take a look [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) to see if there is anything else you can add. Welcome to the site!